# distinguish decimal and string columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, types, decimal, dtype

I need to identify which columns in a dataframe are decimals and which are strings.
Using df.dtypes gives 'object' for both column types:

```
import pandas as pd
import decimal 

data = {'dec1': [1.1, 1.2],'str1': ["a","b"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.dec1 = df.dec1.apply(lambda x: decimal.Decimal(x))

df.dtypes
```

[image]

I am using the following code to know which are decimals, but there has to be a more pythonic way for something so basic. What is it?

```
actual_col_types = df.iloc[0].apply(type)

df_decimals = df.loc[:,actual_col_types==decimal.Decimal]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use `isinstance`, what should be more preferable like type, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance):

```
mask = df.iloc[0].map(lambda x: isinstance(x, decimal.Decimal))
df_decimals = df.loc[:,mask]
print (df_decimals)
                                                dec1
0  1.10000000000000008881784197001252323389053344...
1  1.19999999999999995559107901499373838305473327...
```

Answer (score 1):

Building of [jezrael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61118395/881411), if your data has mixed types in a column, and the first row has something like NaN, then this will fail to detect columns that have the desired type.

Instead, we can check for the presence of *any* decimal value for each column like so:

```
from decimal import Decimal
...

decimal_columns = df.apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: isinstance(y, Decimal)).any())
df_decimals = df.loc[:, decimal_columns]
```